# Grails compare 2 variables in gsp

Tags: grails

I'm trying to compare variables in gsp.

If I do:

```
<g:if test="${p.id.equals(1)}">
```

**I get the result.**

But if i do:

```
<g:if test="${p.id.equals(id)}">
```

**I never get any.**

Comment: where does the `id` variable come from ? Is it a page variable ?

Comment: Come from controller. [id:id]

Comment: if in gsp you echo id value and type with ${id} and ${id.class.name} what you obtain?

Comment: I agree with @Fabiano. It could be a type issue. Comparing a String and an int for example. What are the types involved ?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<g:if test="${p.id == id}">
```